# Нужно вывести сообщение после завершения нескольких обращений к api

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Добрый день в распоряжение  Angular 4 есть метод который обращается к api и апдейтить сущности, это может быть 5 -10 и больше сущностей, то есть  5 -10 обращений к  api.  Мне нужно вывести сообщение если все они прошли успешно, или прекратить операцию если хоть одно обращние зафейлилось.

В наличии вот такая функция

```html
public onMove(item) {
    this.userService.getUserById(this.project.id)
        .map((i) => {
          i.projectId = item.id;
          this.userService.update(i);
        })

    this.contractService.getContractsById(this.project.id)
        .map((i) => {
          i.projectId = item.id;
          this.contractService.update(i);
        })
  }
```

Есть возможность реализовать то что я хочу не модифицируя сервисы к которым обращается метод. То есть в этой функции использую RXJS например?

Comment: можно, `from + mergeMap || forkJoin`

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно